# Why super-initializer parameters cannot be positional if the super-constructor invocation already has positional arguments?

Tags: dart

I'm learning Dart, and I ran into this rule in [a tour of the Dart language](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors):
*Super-initializer parameters cannot be positional if the super-constructor invocation already has positional arguments, but they can always be named:*

```
class Vector2d {
  // ...

  Vector2d.named({required this.x, required this.y});
}

class Vector3d extends Vector2d {
  // ...

  // Forward the y parameter to the named super constructor like:
  // Vector3d.yzPlane({required double y, required this.z})
  //       : super.named(x: 0, y: y);
  Vector3d.yzPlane({required super.y, required this.z}) : super.named(x: 0);
}
```

This sentence with the provided example is quite confusing for me. Because there are no positional arguments used in the `Vector2d` and I don't see any problem in using positional parameters in super-initializer when super-constructor invocation already has positional arguments.
For example:

```
class Vector2d {
  final double x;
  final double y;

  Vector2d(this.x, this.y);
}

class Vector3d extends Vector2d {
  final double z;

  Vector3d(final double x, final double y, this.z) : super(x, y);
}
```

I would like to see an example that would demonstrate that rule with some explanation

Comment: "Because there are no positional arguments used in the `Vector2d`".  The cited example builds upon the previous example where the unnamed `Vector2d` constructor does use positional parameters.  The rule is trying to explain that you can't have `Vector3d(super.x, super.y, this.z);` (presumably because without named parameters, the compiler cannot definitively know which parameters in the derived class should correspond to which parameters in the base class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are not allowed to do is:

```dart
class Super {
  final int x, y;
  Super(this.x, this.y);
}
class Sub extends Super {
  Sub(super.first): super(0);
  //  ^                   ^ super invocation positional argument
  //  ^ positional super parameter
}
```

Here `Sub` has both a positional super-parameter (`super.first`) and an explicit positional argument in the super-invocation (`super(0)`).

The rules for super-parameters do not allow (or cover) this case, because it's not clear whether it should be equivalent to:

```dart
  Sub(int first): super(first, 0);
```

or

```dart
  Sub(int first): super(0, first);
```

Either choice can be argued for, so it was considered safer to not allow the combination at all, and require you to write out the order explicitly as one of the above.
(It looks "obvious" when you write it as `Sub(super.x) : super(0);`, because "obviously" the `super.x` should be matched with the `Super` constructor's `x` parameter, ... but the names of positional super parameters are not important, only their position, like for any other positional parameter. Then name is only used for documentation, and for referencing the value *inside* the function itself.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @lrn, and this is a supplement for lrn`s answer, the code below is my test case for this sentence:

> but the names of positional super parameters are not important, only
> their position

```dart
class Super {
  final int x, y;
  Super(this.x, this.y);
}

class Sub extends Super {
  Sub(super.y, super.x);
}

void main() {
  var s = Sub(1, 2);
  print('x=${s.x}, y=${s.y}');
}
```

```
Result is: x=1, y=2
```